Reasons after look forward to: do they require the -ing form?
I wrote a "look forward to" phrase, and after that I explained the reasons why I look forward to doing that thing.
The phrase I wrote is:

I look forward to learning all those different styles, both for personal curiosity and also to find my own style and adopt it, which goes back to the "Self-improvement" point.

But grammarly would like to change it to:

I look forward to learning all those different styles, both for personal curiosity and also to finding my own style and adopting it, which goes back to the "Self-improvement" point.

I feel that -ing form there unnattural and unnecessary.
I  think grammarly is extending the look forward to + -ing form to the reasons.
But those are not things I would like to pursue, those are the reasons why I would like to pursue the things after the look forward clause.
Who is right?

I would not call them reasons but purposes. If you add in order before to find, Grammarly might be pleased and less confused about two verbs being preceded by to, which is why it expects a parallel structure where there isn't one.
So your sentence would look like this:

I look forward to learning all those different styles, both for personal curiosity and also in order to find my own style and adopt it, which goes back to the "Self-improvement" point.


Yes; it doesn't sound too hot with a bare in order to. ??'I look forward to learning all those different styles['] to find my own style' But I'd prefer further wording: I look forward to learning all those different styles, both to satisfy personal curiosity and also with the hope of finding my own style.'

@EdwinAshworth Yes, that's a fair option. I hoped that once the ambiguity removed, the OP would do his own editing.

Grammarly is confused about what items are being listed with "and". It thinks you're making a list of things that you're looking forward to, and "finding my own style and adopting it" are the next two items in the list. Since we use a gerund after "looking forward to", it says these should be gerunds.
But your list is actually the reasons why you're looking forward to learning. These are indicated using normal infinitives, so your version is correct.

Your intuition is correct. “Look forward to” takes  a gerund, but in this case the only object of the phrase is “learning.” When using “(in order) to” to express purpose, it must be followed by an infinitive. “To” in this case functions not as a preposition but rather as a complement to the infinitive, so it cannot take a gerund object. Grammarly parsed it incorrectly.
